# Multiple columns in a UItableviewcell of different width IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multiple-columns

I had an application on which i need to show  multiple columns in a UItableview with some of them having different widths like spread sheet views.i tried with some available libraries but all of them proving equal width columns.i need to change the width of the individual columns also.[image]

how i will add auto layout constraints if i add 5 decider views is the main issue i am facing when i am doing with UItableview cell.Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: You just have to use a custom `UITableViewCell` where you predefine the width of each "subcell".

Comment: @Larme i am not getting you.can u pls explain?

Comment: With `NSLayoutConstraint`, you can set the width of the "column" in a Custom `UITableViewCell`. You could also use a `UICollectionView`, but it may complexe the implementation and you may don't need to.

Comment: @Larme can u pls give me a sample code of that custom uitableview cell becoz its very urgent for me

Comment: There are two parts, and both have tutorials (that can easily be found on a simple Google Search) : how to use custom `UITableViewCell`, and how to use layout constraints.